# Imports on the fly is adding random Resources and Static ID

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-import

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2; and **"Optimize imports on the fly"** option is checked.

The problem is, when I'm using a resource without its package; for example `sampleString` instead of `R.string.sampleString`

Android Studio adds the below import

```
import static com.a.b.R.string.sampleString;
```

This problem also occurs when I create a new activity, Android Studio imports some random resource to the new created class.

```
import static com.a.b.randompackage.R;
```

I can fix this problem by unchecking "**Optimize imports on the fly**" but I want to keep it checked. Is there any other solution to remove these annoying imports?

Thank you.

My Auto Import Settings:[image]

Comment: That looks absolutely right to me.
The imported class `R` contains all the generated Ids for strings, drawables,  viewIds etc. So it must be imported for java to use

Comment: Of course, you are right. It is not a bug. But I do not want Android Studio to add random resources automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep "Optimize imports on the fly" option checked.

Unchecking "Show import suggestions for static methods and fields" should do the trick:

`Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Show import suggestions for static methods and fields`